# Change argument to -y, --yes, --assume-yes

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal, zsh, shortcuts

Can anyone help me alter this script to automatically YES? y?

I don't need to or want to confirm yes, I just want to pass yes into the shell shortcut.

```
cat << "EOF" >> ~/.zshrc
    #Kill apps that match string
function kill-apps() {
  IFS=$'\n'
  red=$(tput setaf 1)
  normal=$(tput sgr0)
  if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: kill-apps string"
    return 0
  fi
  printf "%s\n" "Finding apps that match “$1”…"
  sleep 1
  processes=($(pgrep -afil "$1"))
  if [ ${#processes[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "No apps found"
    return 0
  else
    printf "%s\n" "${processes[@]}"
    printf "$red%s$normal" "Kill found apps (y or n)? "
    read -r answer
    if [ "$answer" = "y" ]; then
      printf "%s\n" "Killing found apps…"
      sleep 1
      for process in "${processes[@]}"; do
        echo $process | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo kill 2>&1 | grep -v "No such process"
      done
      printf "%s\n" "Done"
      return 0
    fi
  fi
}
EOF
source ~/.zshrc;
kill-apps adobe
```

[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCUXG.jpg)

Some more context

Running this as a shortcut in the Mac shortcuts app functions and returns the argument y or n ? All I want to do is give it a yes command

[Shortcuts outcome from running Shell Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGNHj.png)

Working from this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=mSibcNslSK8&t=547s

and this

https://www.reddit.com/r/AdobeZii/comments/s2rr7z/delete_adobe_creative_cloud_and_stop_all_adobe/

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Have you tried `echo y | kill-apps adobe` ?

Comment: hi @harrymc Amazing! Exactly what I needed ! 
Much appreciated ⭐️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked with the command :

```
echo y | kill-apps adobe
```

Comment: `kill-apps adobe <<< y` should also work.